# Unknown parameter in ren command in batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am new to batch file programming and I am analyzing an existing batch file, which was implemented by a former developer in our company. So I am trying to figure out what he intended to do. I have the following command:

```
for /r %x in (\\Server6\doc_production\*38316468*) do ren "%x" /y \\Server6\doc_production\error\
```

I know that this is a loop command which should go recursively through the given path. But there are some parts which are unknown to me:

1. What is the parameter /y for? I couldn't find anything by googling.
2. What exactly is this command doing?

**UPDATE**:
Thanks for the reply. Many said that this command would move files that match the pattern to the error subfolder. So I tried to test it on my local machine. I created the following directory:

```
C:
├──test
│   └──error
```

And I have inserted a file 38316468.sql in the test folder.
Then I have executed the command:

```
for /r %x in (C:\doc_production\*38316468*) do ren "%x" /y C:\doc_production\error\
```

But nothing happens. The command is executed without any error message. No syntax errors. But it does nothing. It does not move the file, does not rename the file. Why is that like this?

Comment: ren is only for renaming a file. If you want to move, then you need to use the move command.

Comment: @LPChip No. I don't want to do anything. I just want to know what this command is doing. This is something written by a previous developer and I am trying to figure out what he intended to do with this command. What is the /y parameter going to do? What is this command going to do at all?

Comment: Answer : `/y` does nothing because it doesn't exist. You might be using an evolved DOS emulator?

Comment: The command `ren /?` will generally give more info for the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look valid to me.
RENAME (REN) doesn't have a /y parameter and requires the 2nd parameter to be a filename (not a folder like here).
MOVE does have "/y", meaning 'don't bother me with "are you sure" questions when the target already exists and assume I answered "Yes"' and it is OK with a folder as 2nd parameter.
But in case of MOVE the /Y should appear directly after the MOVE command and before the parameters. If you replace REN with MOVE it is still a syntax error.

Anyway: The FOR command creates a list of all files (will look through sub-dirs) matching the pattern *38316468* and then calls the REN for each match in turn.  The REN (should be MOVE) tries to rename (move) each file to the error folder.
But the use of /Y is still wrong for MOVE.

Another problem that error is a sub-folder of the source folder on which FOR is operating. This will cause the command to try to move files onto themselves. (E.g from error folder to error folder.) This may or may not be a problem depending on if the error folder gets cleared later before the FOR command is used again.

Last but not least: Some words of caution:
Using the %X variables in a batch-file requires doubling the % to %%X. On the commandline you can use a single %. 
And %X variables are case-sensitive so %X and %x are not the same thing.

Comment: I have tested what you have explained and written the result in the updated question. I have created a simple directory and a file containing the pattern in the file name. But the command isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Let's dissect it so you can learn what it is doing.

`for /r %x` This command walks down the folder tree starting at `\\Server6\doc_production\*38316468*` path, and executes the DO statement against each matching file.

In your command, the `DO` or action, is `ren` for rename.

The `/y` stops the command prompt from prompting you about overwriting files from source that already exist in destination.

It appears as though it is looking for a wildcard number in the first directory and will rename it and movie it to /error/ folder, but there is no filename to actually make it work. A filename after the /error/ folder would need to be specified for this command to function correctly.

Comment: I tried out what you have written and have inserted a filename after the /error/ but it is not doing anything. I have changed the command to `for /r %x in (C:\test\*38316468*) do move "%x" /y C:\test\error\38316468.sql`. I get no error but also nothing is done.

Comment: @MoProg If you put that in a batch file you have to use %% in stead of % (try "for /?" for help). And you have the /y in the wrong place. That is a syntax error all by itself. `Move /y "%%x" c:\test\error`   Do not specify the target filename because every file moved will overwrite the previous file if you do that. If you only specify the folder name each file is written to that folder retaining its original name.

Comment: @Tonny Unfortunately this is not correct. I tried all combinations. Also the combination you have written: `Move /y "%%x" c:\test\error` within a batch file and directly in the Windows console. None of them is doing anything. It is not moving a file, although not showing an error